# Android http connecting with OkHttp Dont work

Tags: java, android, http, android-activity, okhttp

I am trying to use OkHttp but it keep crashing. Can someone have a quick look and see if you know whats happening. Thank you.

Log cat:

```
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953): FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio.Okio
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:87)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:272)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:174)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:131)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:312)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:235)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:262)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:219)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:192)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:156)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-24 08:34:46.952: E/AndroidRuntime(31953):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is the code sample I am trying to use. Its from a tutorial online (teamtreehouse.com)
Java code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateDisplay();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OkHttp needs Okio, which OkHttp uses for fast I/O and resizable buffers. You can download Okio (latest JAR) [here](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.squareup.okio&a=okio&v=LATEST).

or

Android gradle : `compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'`

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
    <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[for version checks; github okio](https://github.com/square/okio)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a dependency on the 1.0 library of OkHTTP. It is a known report. You may follow it on the link below:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/870

You should also include the [library 1.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okio%7Cokio%7C1.0.0%7Cjar) in the project libs.